# How to modify the android launcher makes desktop App icon to drag effect change?

Tags: android, frameworks

If I want to change the desktop app icon to drag to the left or to the right the other app icon effect, should be in the launcher which method change? Is in the DragController findDropTarget () modify? I can not to find where to modify.In this method to realize right? or the other?

```
private DropTarget findDropTarget(int x, int y, int[] dropCoordinates) {
    final Rect r = mRectTemp;

    final ArrayList<DropTarget> dropTargets = mDropTargets;
    final int count = dropTargets.size();
    for (int i=count-1; i>=0; i--) {
        DropTarget target = dropTargets.get(i);
        if (!target.isDropEnabled())
            continue;

        target.getHitRectRelativeToDragLayer(r);

        mDragObject.x = x;
        mDragObject.y = y; 
        if (r.contains(x, y)) {
            if (mLauncher.isWidgetTools()){
                target.getLocationInDragLayer(dropCoordinates);
                dropCoordinates[0] = x - dropCoordinates[0];
                dropCoordinates[1] = y - dropCoordinates[1];
            } else {
                dropCoordinates[0] = x;
                dropCoordinates[1] = y;
                mLauncher.getDragLayer().mapCoordInSelfToDescendent((View) target, dropCoordinates);
            }

            return target;
     //   }
            }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear ... what do you want ? and what 's the problem ?

Comment: Surprisingly, answer is clearer when you ask clearer, more answers come when you answer more.